# Update build podTemplate for Jenkins X

Tags: jenkins-x

If I modify the pod template in UI as suggested in [adding-your-own-pod-templates](https://jenkins-x.io/architecture/pod-templates/#adding-your-own-pod-templates) my changes get lost on the node restart (we are running on GKE with preemptive nodes)

Is there another reccomendation how to do that? I tried to update `.jx/cloud-environments/env-jx-infra/myvalues.yaml` and run `jx upgrade platform` but that does not seem to  [work yet](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/683). Any chance it will work from `jx install`?

I am kind of hesistating to re-create my environment. As a last resort I will modify the jenkins-x-pod-templates configmap, which will likely help till the next `jx upgrade`

Comment: For the time being I updated the `jenkins` configmap from jx namespace. Updating jenkins-x-pod-templates configmap did not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we recently fixed `jx upgrade platform` so that it can work properly with `myvalues.yaml` files [as described here](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/config/).

there's some docs on how to do this with helm here: https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-custom-builder/